How to recursively map JSON like Plated.transform but taking into account the parent?
In circe, it is possible to recursively modify JSON using Plated.transform:
Plated.transform[Json] { j =>
  j.asNumber match {
    case Some(n) => Json.fromString(n.toString)
    case None    => j
  }
}(json)

See: https://circe.github.io/circe/optics.html#recursively-modifying-json
tl;dr: How can I check for the parent of the json within Plated.transform?
While very elegant, it does not seem to provide any information about the context or hierarchy. In particular, it does not provide the parent. Unfortunately, in JSON it is often necessary to consider the parent of a nested object or the entire hierarchy to avoid ambiguity.
Using this as an example:
{
  "customer": {
      "name": "Jane Doe"
  },
  "seller": {
      "name": "Jon Doe"
  }
}

Let's assume we want to recursively replace all customer names with "N/A", but not seller names.
Of course, it would be possible to pattern match on the parent object. However: If the parent object contains any other data that should be transformed, this then has to be done manually.
Ideally, one could write, e.g.:
Plated.transform[Json] { j =>
  j.asString match {
    case Some(n) if j.hCursor.up.… == "customer" == " => Json.fromString("N/A")
    case None    => j
  }
}(json)

Alas, the up cursor seems to always fail.
So: How do I best approach this issue?
